# Build JSON Tree from Array using node string

Tags: javascript

I am following the example from this link [Build tree array from JSON in JavaScript](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/build-tree-array-from-json-in-javascript) to generate my desired tree output. What I wanted to do was to make the "name" property value as the property name itself and remove the code property from the result. I tried to play with it but I have a little knowledge on how it works.

Codepen Link: [json tree](https://codepen.io/cedetel/pen/xxPmJzv)

Here is my desired result:

```
[
    {
        "one": "default value",
        "children": [
            {
                "one one": "default value"
            },
            {
                "one two": "default value"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "two": "default value"
    },
    {
        "three": "default value"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
el
```

build a new object with a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and take the reference of `map[el.code]` later in

```
map[parent].children.push(map[el.code]);
```

```js
const
    arr = [{ code: "1", name: "one" }, { code: "1.1", name: "one one" }, { code: "1.2", name: "one two" }, { code: "2", name: "two" }, { code: "3", name: "three" }],
    transformToTree = (arr, root = '') => {
         let map = {}, last = [root], level = 0;
         map[root] = {};
         arr.forEach(el => {
              let parent = root;
              while (level && last[level].length >= el.code.length) level--;
              parent = last[level];
              level++;
              last.length = level;
              last.push(el.code);
              map[el.code] = { [el.name]: 'default value' };
              map[parent].children = map[parent].children || [];
              map[parent].children.push(map[el.code]);
         });
         return map[root].children;
    };    
console.log(transformToTree(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That was what I did but it did not include the children.

Comment: @Dekso, please see edit.